# Why block/thread index in cuda is not similar to two dimension array in C?

Tags: cuda

This is picture from cuda programming guide:
[image]

This may be very stupid question but it sounds really confusing for me. Shouldn't it be like:

```
Block (0,0) --> Block (0,1) --> Block (0,2) // This is supposedly row 0
Block (1,0) --> Block (1,1) --> Block (1,2) // This is supposedly row 1
```

Is this on intention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CUDA threadblock or grid index ordering is x,y,z

For example the block (1,0) is the second block in the x-dimension, the first block in the y-dimension

When you suggest that (0,0), (0,1), (0,2) all belong to the same row, you're simply reflecting a specific view (row, column) of index arrangement.

There is no required mapping between x,y and row,column.  You can arrange it any way you wish.

It is customary in CUDA C/C++ to use the thread/block x dimension to refer to the matrix column, because this facilitates good coalescing for memory access within a warp.  In CUDA fortran, however, it may be customary to reverse these (for good coalescing), as the underlying matrix storage pattern in memory for a fortran array is different than for a  C array.